# How can I use MODE to get most occuring number with match

Tags: excel

I have two lists on two sheets.

Sheet 1 is a stock list of the warehouse. It shows the SKU (stock keeping unit)/article number and the number of boxes.
Because it does not show how many boxes each pallet has I need to use data from inbound history to match how many boxes there usually is.

Sheet 2 has SKU/article number, date, number of boxes. That means it's a big list of each pallet received and the number of boxes on each pallet.

I first tried to use MAX() to find the maximum number of boxes and use that but it seems there are some errors in the list, so I want to use MODE().

To get MAX() I can use `{=MAX(IF(Data=C2290;Kolli;-1))}` where Data is a named range of sheet 2 and kolli is a named range of the number of boxes in sheet 2.
It looks for the SKU/article number (column C) in the if() and returns the max number of boxes from sheet 2.
It works, but if I replace MAX with MODE to the the most occurring number it doesn't work. `{=MODE(IF(Data=C2290;Kolli;-1))}`.

Anyone who knows how I can use MODE() to match SKU/article number and return the most occurring number of boxes from sheet 2?
This needs to be a formula and not VBA.

```
SKU     date     Boxes  weight
219707  20160519    24  816
219707  20160520    24  816
219707  20160521    24  816
219707  20160523    24  816
219707  20160524    24  816
219707  20160525    24  816
219707  20160526    24  816
219707  20160527    24  816
219707  20160528    24  816
219707  20160529    24  816
219707  20160530    24  816
219707  20160531    24  816
219707  20160627    23  782
219707  20160615    20  680
219707  20160623    20  680
219707  20160624    20  680
219707  20160512    20  680
219707  20160513    20  680
219707  20160529    20  680
219707  20160513    18  612
219707  20160624    16  544
219707  20160628    16  544
219707  20160512    16  544
```

Comment: Sample data will be helpful.

Comment: @Mrig Sample data from sheet2 is added

Comment: Why don't you build a pivot table? Number of boxes in rows. Filter by SKU, some other field in Values, set to count.

Comment: @teylyn Pivot table on the list above? I just tried but I can't get the MODE value in a pivot, or can I? I can get average, min and max, but none of them is really interesting.

Comment: @teylyn Sorry didn't see your edit til I posted my comment. Count is not the correct value I want. In the list above I want it to return 24 as 24 is the most occurring value in column C. And I don't see that option in pivot

Comment: Try this: `{=MODE(IF(Data=C2290;Kolli))}`

Comment: @Mrig That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
{=MODE(IF(Data=C2290;Kolli;-1))}
```

write

```
{=MODE(IF(Data=C2290;Kolli))}
```

Answer (score 2):

A pivot table can summarize and sort by count of boxes. Sort the count column descending and then show only top 1

[image]

Comment: I will look in to this. I like Pivot tables as they are only updated on command as opposed to formulas that drains the computer of all power

Comment: I got this working too. However I need to get all SKUs MODE at the same time so pivot may work but will be messy. But thank you for the suggestion, it was helpful :-)

Comment: This solution will work for all SKUs, just need to clear the filter on `SKU` field and move it to the Rows Data and it will show the top count for each `SKU` (see figure) [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qY1o5.png